# How to show value of log attribute in monitor with log.attribute.ATTRIBUTE

Tags: datadog

I am created a monitor in Datadog. I want to extract email from the log which is available in the JSON of the log at `limitedSessionData.user.email`.

When I'm typing the monitor, the screenshot below is of the hint that comes up. However I tried the following but not of them work:

- `"{{log.attributes.limitedSessionData.user.email}}" - email this guy asking if he needs help.`
- `"{{log.attributes.[limitedSessionData.user.email]}}" - email this guy asking if he needs help.`
- `"{{log.attributes[limitedSessionData.user.email]}}" - email this guy asking if he needs help.`
- `"{{log.attributes[@limitedSessionData.user.email]}}" - email this guy asking if he needs help.`

Any ideas how to do this? Does the log attribute need to be faceted?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```
"{{log.attributes.[params.body.fullName]}}" - email this guy
```

More information can be found here:

- https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notify/variables/

Comment: No problem man, that was a tricky problem I had and I'm sure others struggled too.